# Which <item> attribute needs to be set for declaring an action provider?

Tags: android

I recently started learning Android development. I'm looking at the action bar and am a little confused.

What the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider) said is:

> To declare an action provider, **supply the `actionViewClass` attribute
>   in the menu <item> tag** with a fully-qualified class name for
>   an ActionProvider.

According the context, I think what the tutorial actually meant was `actionProviderClass`, not `actionViewClass`.

Am I correct, or are the `actionViewClass` and `actionProviderClass` both the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be `actionProviderClass`.

The [Menu Resource documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) shows that there is both an `android:actionViewClass` attribute and an `android:actionProviderClass` attribute.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think they are difference, set ShareActionProvider to the actionViewClass attribute will cause a class cast exception